# A proper way to detect Tablet or Mobile in Qt using non-native tools

Tags: android, ios, qt, size, screen

I have a purpose to determine tablet or mobile I deploy the application on.

As I deploy the app both iOS, Android, Linux Desktop and Windows, it is desirable to use non-native tools.

But as a part of experiment I tried the following trick for android (method of java class):

**Experiment #1**

```
public class JniUtilities {
    public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        Log.d("INDENTIFICATOR >> ", "HEJJ, I AM CALLED!");
        return ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    }
}
```

**Result:** It seems to work fine, but not applicable for other operating systems :(

**Experiment #2**

Let's try Qt Framework tools. Here I can learn device physical size having `QScreen class` instance. As criteria of `isTablet` I shall use condition of `diagonal > 7.0 inches`.

```
qreal Utils::getDiagInch() {
    QScreen *srn = qApp->screens().at(0);
    qreal w = srn->physicalSize().width();
    qreal h = srn->physicalSize().height();
    qreal inches = qSqrt(w * w + h * h) / 25.4; // millimeters to inches
    qDebug() << "physical diagonal >> " << inches;
    return inches;
}
```

For experiment I used `HTC ONE X` phone.

`(qreal Utils::getDiagInch()): physical width >>  3.38583
(qreal Utils::getDiagInch()): physical height >>  6.02362
(qreal Utils::getDiagInch()): physical diagonal >>  6.90998`

As we can see from official manufacturer's properties, the phone has

`width of 2.3 inches,
height of 4.1 inches and
diagonal of 4.7 inches`

Okay. Having incorrect values, we, anyway, obtained the correct result:

`HTC ONE X is PHONE as it has diagonal less than 7.0 inches.`

**Result:** the METHOD is UNRELIABLE.

Okay. Another one experiment:

**Experiment #3**

Suggest that problem is in Qt Framework implementation, returning incorrect values. Then if we ask Android native tools for Display physical size, it should return a different result:

`java-class:`

```
public class MyActivityJo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        double physWidth = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
        Log.d("ph width >> ", Double.toString(physWidth));
        double physHeight = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi;
        Log.d("ph height >> ", Double.toString(physHeight));
        double physDiag = Math.sqrt(physWidth * physWidth + physHeight * physHeight);
        Log.d("ph diagonal >> ", Double.toString(physDiag));
    }
}
```

output:

`D/ph width >> (27948): 3.380281686782837
D/ph height >> (27948): 6.009389877319336
D/ph diagonal >> (27948): 6.894858300184821`

**Result:** DisplayMetrics returns incorrect values, too.

**OVERALL**

I've tried many of playmarket apps. They know how to exactly answer the question: no one app was wrong detecting tablet/phone. How do they do that? Do they use native tools? Or there is universal, non-native method by Qt Framework to solve the issue unambiguously??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to get dpi value of a screen, you can follow this method:

in .pro

```
android{
QT += androidextras
}
```

include

```
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#endif
```

code:

```
qreal m_dpi;
qreal m_pixelRatio;

#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
QAndroidJniObject qtActivity =    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
QAndroidJniObject resources = qtActivity.callObjectMethod("getResources","()Landroid/content/res/Resources;");
QAndroidJniObject displayMetrics = resources.callObjectMethod("getDisplayMetrics","()Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics;");
int density = displayMetrics.getField<int>("densityDpi");
m_dpi = density;
m_pixelRatio = 1;
#else
m_dpi = qApp->primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch();
m_pixelRatio = qApp->primaryScreen()->devicePixelRatio();
#endif
```

once you get the dpi, if you have to find the scaling factor with respect to your reference device.

```
qreal m_dpiRef = 132; //reference device dpi (ipad);
double scalingFactor = 1;

if(m_dpi>0&&m_dpiRef >0)
 scalingFactor=m_dpi/m_dpiRef;
```

physical size:

```
width/m_dpi //should give the physical width of screen in inches.
```

To check if the device is tablet or mobile in android devices, a mdpi(160 dpi) android device with 600dp minimum width can be considered a tablet (may vary depending upon your requirements).

```
width*160/m_dpi >= 600 //to check if the screen size is large enough(tablet).
```

I have verified the code for Android and iOS. 
You may have to use following code for windows. (Please verify).

```
m_dpi = qApp->primaryScreen()->logicalDotsPerInch()*qApp->primaryScreen()->devicePixelRatio();
```

Comment: thank you!
**The problem is:** QScreen evaluates _physicalSize()_ incorrectly, because _QScreen::physicalDotsPerInch()_ returns wrong value, but _DisplayMetrics::densityDpi_ returns correct value.

Test Results for **HTC ONE X**:
QScreen::physicalDotsPerInch() : 212.574 ppi
DisplayMetrics::densityDpi : 320 ppi
From Documentation : ~ 312 ppi